# Sub view by variable name in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have an AngularJS app with these states registeren in `ui-router`

```
.state('edit', {
    url: "/edit",
    templateUrl: "views/edit.html",
    controller: "EditController"
  })
  .state('edit.tvshow', {
    url: "/:showName",
    templateUrl: "views/edit.show.html",
    controller: "EditShowController"
  })
```

I also have this `edit.html` view:

```
<div ng-controller="EditController">

    <ul>

        <li ng-repeat="show in shows">

            <a ui-sref=".{{ showName : show.name}}">{{ show.name }}</a>
            <img src="img/artwork/{{ show.image_name }}.png">

        </li>

    </ul>

    <div ui-view></div>

</div>
```

Everything works fine when I go to `www.mywebapp.com/#/edit/dexter`. However, when I go to `www.mywebapp.com/#/edit` and then click on dexter, nothing happens...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got wrong `ui-sref=".{{ showName : show.name}}"`

Try changing it to something similar to this `ui-sref=".tvshow({ showName: show.name})"`

See more, about `ui-sref` directive here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref